# Use custom class for Spring logging

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, log4j

I'm using Spring with 3rd party product API. This product is using its own class for logging

it looks something like this:

```
import x.y.z.PluginLogger;
public class MyLogger extends PluginLogger{

public MyLogger(){
    super("myLogger-log4j-conf.xml");
    super.init();
}

}
```

now I'm initiating this logger in my code:

```
public static Logger logger = new MyLogger();
```

Now my question is simple I can initate this class file in Spring Application Context.

```
<bean id="logger" class="z.y.x.Logger" parent="pluginLogger">
<bean id="pluginLogger"  class="x.y.z.ParentLogger">
```

How can I tell Spring to use logger bean as its default logger? In other words I would like to use this bean as default logger for Spring framework and for my code I writing.?

Hope I maid myself clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring uses commons-logging.
You can create an integration between commons-logging and your logger.
See [this guide](http://commons.apache.org/logging/guide.html#Creating%20a%20Log%20Implementation)

Comment: I know this article, but still I don't get how can I tell spring to use my custom Logger? I understand that my custom Logger should implement org.apache.commons.logging.Log interface.

Comment: You don't need to tell Spring anything. It will happen if you follow the guide. Commons-logging will find your Logger and use it.

Comment: Implement Log and LogFactory that creates the Log. That's all. See how Slf did that: https://github.com/ceki/slf4j/blob/master/jcl-over-slf4j/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SLF4JLogFactory.java and https://github.com/ceki/slf4j/blob/master/jcl-over-slf4j/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/SLF4JLog.java